# State of Debian Stable (Stretch) Repository between time of two versions (e.g. 9.8 to 9.9)

Tags: debian, repository

Lets say I have the repository URL set to "http://ftp.debian.org/debian/" and the distribution is set to "stretch" with component "main".

Q:

1. Are the packages between the time/development from Debian 9.8 to 9.9 changed within this repository, i.e. is it possible if they are altered/updated?
2. Or do only the packages change in debian-security and are (maybe) moved to "stable" Debian (non security) in next version?
3. Or something different?

I think, that #1 is the case, but I am not sure. If yes, is there a possibility to get the exact state of packages of a certain Debian Stretch version, e.g. released Debian Stretch 9.8 (or also Debian 9.2) via URL (not by CD-ROM, etc.)?

Comment: See https://snapshot.debian.org/ for snapshots of the archive on any given date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of the main repository don’t change between point releases. Security updates are uploaded to the security repository, and other updates are uploaded to [the “updates” repository](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates) (`stretch-updates` for Debian 9). When a point release is cut, all the updates in the security and update repositories (and other queued changes, from [the “proposed updates” repository](https://wiki.debian.org/StableProposedUpdates)) are merged into the main repositories.

It isn’t possible to find the exact state of packages of a certain Debian release in the main repositories though. However you can use [the snapshot repository](https://snapshot.debian.org/) to find the state of the repositories on a given date, and [the release notes](https://www.debian.org/News/2019/20190216), [the repository changelog](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/ChangeLog), and associated package changelogs to figure out what version of a given package was in any given point release.